# Problem while saving multiple pictures inside OnDraw()

Tags: java, android, canvas

I am new to Android and I am having trouble to save he multiple pictures in `onDraw(Canvas canvas);`

Here my code to draw the images in canvas

```
canvas.drawBitmap(resize, 40, 100, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(resizeImage1, 400, 100, null);
canvas.drawText(CameraText, 100, 175, paint);
```

Here my code to save the images.

```
Bitmap toDisk = Bitmap.createBitmap(resizeImage1);
canvas.setBitmap(toDisk);
toDisk.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/pig.jpg")));
```

My problem here is that I can pass the single variable only `resizeImage1`. I cannot pass `CameraText`,`resize`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

<s>Don't you need to try to save the canvas graphic not the bitmap?</s>

That way you can apply your modification to the image (via canvas) then save

The canvas object changes the bitmap you assigned using `setBitmap` and then you apply changes to the bitmap using the canvas functions. So something along this lines should be similar to what you're looking (copied from your example code)

```
Bitmap toDisk = Bitmap.createBitmap(resizeImage1);
canvas.setBitmap(toDisk);
canvas.drawBitmap(resize, 40, 100, null);
canvas.drawBitmap(resizeImage1, 400, 100, null);
canvas.drawText(CameraText, 100, 175, paint);
toDisk.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, new FileOutputStream(new File("/mnt/sdcard/pig.jpg")));
```

Comment: How Can i do this sir Kindly Help me?

Comment: Read up more on canvas, seems that the above code could do what you're looking?

Comment: Sir Nothing Changes in My Code ,i Got Same output and u Also Pass the Single variable only.i Can view the Single Pictures only.i Cannot view the CameraText,resize.

Comment: I am struggling with your English and am not sure of what you're asking. Perhaps you could edit your question to include examples of what you want and your inputs? Images are appreciated.